# Flutter how to put a cents input in my amount

Tags: flutter

[image]

Good day my aim here is to add a cents in my input like 794.24 cause in my formatter i had online put 794.00 when the users completely fill up the feild.

```
 class _PaymentState extends State<Payment> {
Here is my numberFormat i used 
     final money = NumberFormat("#,##0", "en_US");
         @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            ),
            body: Form(
              key: _key,
              child: Center(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
```

This is the field that the user inputs the OR number.

```
Padding(
                    padding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0, horizontal: 16.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters,
                      validator: (e) {
                        if (e.isEmpty) {
                          return "Please input a OR Number";
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      onSaved: (e) => ornum = e,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'OR NUMBER',
                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Color(0xff083663),
                          )),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder()),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Here is my Input Formatter that give a currency when the user inputs an amount.

```
            Padding(
                    padding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0, horizontal: 16.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      inputFormatters: [
                        WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                        CurrencyFormat()
                      ],
                      onSaved: (e) => payment = e,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'AMOUNT',
                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Color(0xff083663),
                          )),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder()),
                    ),
                   ),
                   ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
      }
    
    }
```

Here is the code extension that i use to format my input field

```
class CurrencyFormat extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    if (newValue.selection.baseOffset == 0) {
      return newValue;
    }
    double value = double.parse(newValue.text);
    final money = new NumberFormat("###,###,###", "en_us");

    String newText = money.format(value);

    return newValue.copyWith(
        text: newText,
        selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: newText.length));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enable decimal on textfield and also add a regex

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

TextField(
          keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
          inputFormatters: [
            FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp('[0-9.,]')),
          ],
        ),
```

then just create a function for your CurrencyFormat to:

```
 String currencyPrice(String textFieldValue) {
    double value = double.parse(textFieldValue);
    final money = new NumberFormat("###,###,###", "en_us");

    return money.format(value);
  }
```

Comment: i want also to add a comma like 7,944.24

Comment: the the example its already added on regex

Comment: but when i input 1244.26 there is no comma showing  like this 1,244.26

Comment: I just tested it again when I type comma on textfield its showing comma and decimal.. Try to debug your code a bit.. Or are talking about the result there's no comma?. run the code given first that should work dont add anything first.

Comment: so in my class currency format ill add the currencyprice function you have given ?sorry newbie